# Widgets disappear after upgrading app from flutter to native ios

Tags: ios, swiftui, ioswidgets

I do have a flutter app. I developed an iOS app with the same bundle id so that when installed through testflight, it overrides the flutter app. Issue is, the large and medium widgets installed through flutter app disappears while the small widget persists after the update. Did anyone faced similar scenario ever. Deployment target is iOS 16 and above. Testing on iOS 17. Thanks.